# React automatic PDF printing for tickets kiosque

Tags: pdf-generation

So I'm developing a react application for a tickets kioske in a queue management system and the auto-printing feature after clicking the `print` button is driving me crazy.
here's the code for generating the PDF ticket file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Document, Page, Text, View, StyleSheet } from '@react-pdf/renderer';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: '1cm'
  },
  section: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    flexGrow: 1,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 14
  },
  bold: {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
});




const Ticket = ({ clientNumber, guichet, datetime }) => {
  return (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Merci pour votre patience</Text>
          <Text style={[styles.text, styles.bold]}>Votre numéro est:</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{clientNumber}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Ticket pris à {datetime}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text}></Text>
          <Text style={[styles.text, styles.bold]}>Vous serez servi par le guichet:</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{guichet}</Text>
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};

export default Ticket;
```

**And here's the client side component where the print button is:**

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Impression.css"
import { PDFDownloadLink } from '@react-pdf/renderer'
import Header from "../Components/Header/Header";
import Footer from "../Components/Footer/footer";
import Ticket from "./Ticket";
import { API_URL } from "../../Config";

function Impression(){
    const [params] = useState(useParams());
    const [num, setNum] = useState('');
    const [guichet, setGuichet] = useState('');
    const [datetime, setDatetime] = useState('');

    function extractNumbersAndJoin(string) {
        const numbers = string.match(/\d+/g);
      
        if (!numbers) {
          return '';
        }
      
        return numbers.join(' ou ');
      }
      

    useEffect(() => {
        const {id, Service} = params
        fetch(`${API_URL}/Inscription/${id}/${Service}`, {
            method: "post"
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(RecievedData => {
            console.log(RecievedData)
            let currentdate = new Date(); 
            let datetime = currentdate.getHours() + ":"
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
                + currentdate.getSeconds() + " le "
                + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + currentdate.getFullYear();

            setNum(RecievedData.num);
            setGuichet(extractNumbersAndJoin(RecievedData.guichets))
            setDatetime(datetime)

        })
    }, [])



    return(
            <div className="container">
                <Header />
                    <div className="thankyou-container">
                        <div className="loading-container">
                            <div className="loader"></div>
                            <h1>Merci de patienter</h1>
                            <p>Cliquez sur le bouton pour imprimer le ticket</p>
                            <PDFDownloadLink document={<Ticket clientNumber={num} guichet={guichet}   datetime={datetime}/>} filename="ticket.pdf" >
                                {({blob, url, loading, error}) => 
                                    loading ? ""
                                    : <button className="pdf-button"> Imprimer </button>
                                }
                            </PDFDownloadLink>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
    )
}

export default Impression;
```

Now I know that the Impression component isn't printing the file but downloading it using `PDFDownloadLink` but I tried a lot of other things like `react-to-print` library and nothing worked, so any suggestions?